# What does 'authograph' mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In the field of Textual Criticism, the word 'autograph' does not refer just to a signature but to a manuscript, traditionally hand-written on parchment or vellum, by either the writer themselves or by a scribe, from dictation.

But I recently came across the word 'authograph' which I assume is being used in the same context as it is used by John Burgon, a renowned textual critic.

The [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=authograph&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cauthograph%3B%2Cc0) shows its use and it appears to be still a valid, and not archaic, word. But I can nowhere find - anywhere - a dictionary that contains it, either online or at home.

Does this word mean what I think it means (the original handwritten manuscript of an author) or does it mean something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *authograph* appears precisely twice in OED3, within the entry for *autograph:*

> Forms: 
>   α. 16 **authograph,** 16 **autographe,** 16– **autograph.**
>
> The form *authograph* is perhaps influenced by **author** *n.*

This indicates that the word was in use four hundred years ago*, but isn't now. However, searching for the word yields an interesting extract which includes the words "now especially", indicating that it does have a reasonably fixed modern meaning:

> 1. **authograph** in *autograph, n.* and *adj.*
>      ...A manuscript written in the author's own handwriting. Now *esp.*: a composer's handwritten musical score. Cf. holograph...

So yes: it appears it does mean the original handwritten manuscript of an author or composer.

[Link to result](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=authograph&_searchBtn=Search&redirectedFrom) (logged-in subscribers to OED only)

*It's not clear whether *16* refers to 16th century or 1600s (17th century), but in this case that difference is not particularly significant.

Comment: @NigelJ Your profile indicates you're in the UK. Your county library service should provide you with one for nothing (or at least, it's included in your Council Tax). That's how I have mine.

Comment: I shall be on the doorstep at 9:00 am demanding my rights.

Comment: "Centuries of use are denoted by the first two digits of their years, e.g. 17 denotes the century 1700-1799." *[Guide to the Third Edition of the OED](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/guide-to-the-third-edition-of-the-oed/)*